# How to redirect example.com to http://example.com?

Tags: redirects, godaddy, http, blogger, no-www

I have a blog at blogger.com, for which I got a domain name from godaddy.com. Recently I have decided to put some google AdSense ads on it to see how that goes.

The problem I encountered is that AdSense will not take the URL
http://www.example.com, apparently it has to be http://example.com
My blog is accesible at example.com and www.example.com
but not at http://example.com as Adsense requires.

I've been looking for an answer for few hours now but all I came up with was about forwarding to the naked domain(which I already did) and editing the robots.txt file (which i have no clue about).

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Chrome (and possibly other browsers) hide the `http://` part in the browser address bar, but it is there. If your site is accessible on `example.com` then you are accessing it at http://example.com/ whether your browser is showing that or not.

Comment: Although if you type in `example.com` some browsers automatically add the `www.`   So maybe their site isn't available without the `www`.

Comment: I don't understand how this has anything to do with AdSense and the question.

Comment: Mind you - you should forward your www to non-www or vice versa. For SEO purposes only one version should be available and the other should forward to the version you choose. Otherwise people link to both version and you end up being less competitive within SERPs. In fact you will end up competing with yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps these blogger specific instructions will help. https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-redirect-my-domain-from-non-www-to-www-on-Blogger which is an example of someone going from http://example.com to http://www.example.com.

This is called the `Canonical URL issue` https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-www-and-non-www-URL-How-it-makes-a-difference-to-the-Google

Comment: You should expand your answer to include the contents of the links as link only answers are considered low quality as those links can rot leaving the answer as useless.

Comment: Thanks for replying John, and I do agree my answer is low quality as defined here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info I've no idea how blogger works and thought these links would be useful to the OP. Which is a similar spirit to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259 what Jon Skeet said in his comment about a low-quality answer being better than no answer.. Just trying to help and make SO useful :-) I appreciate it's hard getting high-quality answers on SO.